# Proper way to intercommunicate between state change in redux store and corresponding react state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, react-state

I have a react application which uses the redux state management tool alongside local native state management i.e react (component/container) state.
Suppose there's a form component whose data is stored in the react state. The API call is made and handled via sagas which updates the Redux Store accordingly. How do I change the react state e.g change the form state key to `loading: false`  or generally how would I update the form(controlled form or uncontrolled) with the data after the saga receives the data from API call. For controlled form there would be a container component which manages the props for that form but again how to update the container's state then ? 
I dont want to store the data in both redux and react state, especially if that data is meant to be for local store, not redux store

If I use the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method, again I would need to have stored that data in e.g reduxState to be ultimately copied or computed and put into react State.
I am using the approach described below for now but I was wondering whether there's anything else any of you can suggest.

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/907

Sample code of what I am using is as follows, similar to the one described in the link

```
validate = (drops, senderDetails, revalidate) => {
    const { largestLCU, actions: { validateDispatch } } = this.props
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => validateDispatch(drops, senderDetails,
      requestBatchSize, defaultMaxCapPerStop, defaultMarkerColor, largestLCU, resolve, revalidate))
    promise.then(({ success, data }) => {
      if (success) {
        this.setState((state) => {
          const { messages } = this.props
          return {
            ...state,
            senderDetails: {
              ...state.senderDetails,
              ...data,
            },
            currentStatus: {
              ...state.currentStatus,
              isAllValid: messages.length === 0,
              isFileSelected: false,
            },
            csvFile: null,
            loading: false,
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

validateDispatch dispatches an action, the redux saga intercepts, performs Api call and gives back certain data to update the react state after the Promise is resolved. Of course this is a compromise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, I think you'd want to leverage redux-saga for it's strength: handling async side-effects.  Your sample code bypasses the benefits of redux-saga by using promises in a callback function instead.  There's nothing stopping you from using redux-saga with say redux thunks or promised based callbacks, but you have to weigh whether it's worth it (or needed) to have multiple ways of handling async side-effects in your project.

There seems to be a couple of issues you're juggling.

One concern is duplication of data in redux store and component state.

> I dont want to store the data in both redux and react state, especially if that data is meant to be for local store, not redux store

What data are you referring to?

If you mean the actual server payload, then it's pretty conventional to store the server payload in the redux store and have react-redux update the component on redux state change. This is the uni-directional data flow upon which redux is based on.

If you mean "derived" data (data that can inferred from the server payload), then I'd recommend not duplicating this data in both the redux store and component state.  Only storing the minimum amount of data needed in redux store is recommended - else you run into issues of consistency and maintaining/update multiple copies of the same data.  You can look into [redux data normalizers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) or selectors (e.g. reselect) to handle this.  [Redux's docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) have pretty good explanations for these concepts.

Since you are using local component state, then perhaps you might look into [react's context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which serves as an alternative to redux's state management.  I've been using the context api with local component state, but generally my usages have been limited to truly "temporary/ephermeral" UI state (e.g. whether a popup is shown/hidden).  I haven't tried (or needed) to use react's context to bypass redux-saga/react-redux as in your sample code above.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It was indeed helpful and provided a lot suitable alternatives with their ups and downs.
 About some of your points :
1) " If you mean the actual server payload, then it's pretty conventional to store the server payload " . I am using a form to store sender(user) details for submission. A part of response after submission gives further details about the sender so I am storing the object in react State. I dont think keeping them separate would be good, no ?

Comment: 2) Some changes only have to deal with an event completion like "received response from server" and then I set the React's loading state to 'false' so I think there has to be intercommunication here or should I move this loading state to Redux ?

Comment: 3) For derived data, yeah I am using the same approach you described since any change in props triggers a re-render and a recomputation so this re-render is actually the communication / synchronization mechanism here but for other stuff like nullifying state in e.g form component after receiving data we still need a communication mechanism. Having flags in redux store so 'getDerivedStateFromProps' can work accordingly, even if optimizaed by selectors still means complex logic esp in large projects with large state trees and an increase in flags(storage) in redux store

Comment: 4) You are right that we definitely lose serialibilty as mentioned in the link in my question about using Promises. But here using promises should iincur atmost one level nesting, and handling async functionality/ side effects is still executed in sagas right? but yeah the illusion of a synchronous action dispatch is lost through use of promises but I still find this a worthy compromise solution compared to other compromise solutions, no ? What do you think?
I would be really glad if you can take the time to answer/discuss these queries :)

Comment: 4) I think two issues that are surfaced from a promised based approach is testability and flexibility/maintainability of code.  I've been so ingrained in testing via redux-saga that I'm not sure how one goes about testing a promised styled callback inside a component.  Async actions are deceptively simple on the surface but has potential pitfalls in edge cases.  The sample code does handle the error use case, but it seems that caution would be needed to expand that code to handle more use cases.

Comment: 3) For me, the distinction is drawn b/t can the comp be self servicing (capable of maintaining its own state) or does the comp need outside help (from react context or redux store). If I'm understanding the problem correctly, then the issue is that you're facing a gray area b/t using outside help and local comp state.  I don't have general solutions for this other than try to keep redux store as small as possible by using react context or local comp state.  If you have a specific issue, then that can help direct the conversation.

Comment: 2) One thing I realized in my app is that loading state is actually two things.  Loading waiting on server response and loading waiting on UI painting or other component processing.  So on the surface, loading looked quite simple, but it ended up being more nuanced.  I think if you can safely determine the loading state via props, then that's the best solution b/c redux store isn't needed.  But otherwise, you need to rely on redux store b/c the sagas are what coordinates the state updates.  As an aside, I'm looking forward to using react suspense one day to solve this at some level.

Comment: 1) Yeah, I'd prob go with storing that user object in redux state b/c I wouldnt want to arbitrarily split up domain objects -- unless it makes sense to partition the user object.  For example, user can have a profile and preferences related props.  So if the comp that comes after the form submission only cares about user preferences then maybe that makes sense.  In general, I'd prob lean towards making things understandable and simpler in this case, than trying to micro manage the state too much.

Comment: btw, what is "serialibility" @Omer ?

Comment: Sorry about using the vague term I don't fully understand even (I just used it based on the [link](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/907) in my posted question since the people there used it and I thought maybe you might know it- I assume it means something about losing the synchronous feel/ component has to be aware that certain actions are asynchronous and some are not , the exact same thing what sagas are meant to resolve among other things)

Comment: 1) Yeah that makes sense

Comment: 2) Actually I was doing a redux refactor of the current React application. The original version had a container component which passed the loading prop to **all** three of its child components since the loading is interconnected between them. I suppose storing loading in redux can be fine for the refactor since the loading here, indicating the state of api action also syncs with the state of the components i.e whether the components should display a spinner or not, but I think problems may arise when scaling the project or if the components need to have their own separate loading animations

Comment: I dont think setting aside different loading keys for each of them in the redux store would be good, no ? If the forms are mountable , then they are of very ephemeral nature and wouldn't make sense to have their loaders inside redux store. However, at the same time, the sagas handle this async API call and they would need some way to communicate with those components to indicate a successful or error response

Comment: 3) My issue is more like that "I think certain elements belong in the store and certain in local component state but certain saga async side effects like API call result in changes in both the store and component(s) state, the former is easy to achieve inside sagas using yield put but the latter seems to be problematic" 

4) I couldn't agree more about your comment of using Promises. It is definitely a compromise but I am not sure what else can better cater to my above dilemma (in point 3)